# What does "return @[blah, blah] [self.foo]" mean?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am following some tutorials and there is a line of code which I do not really understand:

```
- (NSString *)rankAsString
{
return @[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"D",@"K"][self.rank];
}
```

What is returned? Thanks!

Comment: Why the down votes, the code is worse than the question! Could have been written more clearly in two lines, the first creating an `NSArray`, the second indexing into the array.

Comment: What tutorial where did you find that?  It is awful, but you shouldn't be downvoted for not knowing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is also known as a [Lookup Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) and can be used in place of switch/case or if/else in situations such as this.

That is, the code creates an NSArray (of NSString) to use as a lookup and then retrieves the string at the specified ordinal position - e.g. an Ace ("A") is rank 1, and a King ("K") is rank 13.

Consider if the code has been written as:

```
NSArray* array = @[@"?", @"A", ..., @"K"];
return array[self.rank];
```

Here it can be seen that the array is a seperate expression. The `@[..]`, `@".."` and `array[..]` forms are covered in the [Clang documentation on
OBJECTIVE-C LITERALS](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html); the syntax can be used in Apple LLVM Compiler 4.

Comment: Note, this re-creates the lookup table every time the method is called. That's rather wasteful, because the table doesn't change. An appropriate solution would be to define a `static NSArray *array;` variable, then use [`dispatch_once()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_once.3.html) to initialize the array.

Comment: @user2864740: There's nothing special about arrays created by literals. They have the same ownership and memory management characteristics as arrays created with `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]`.

Comment: @user2864740: I'm not sure what you mean. Array literals are just syntactic sugar for `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:count:]`.